# Express session deleted on page reload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, passport.js, express-session

I started my first backend-frontend website. In this project I use: express, react with typescript, mongodb, passportjs. It will be a single page application. I got as far as redirecting to the "home" page after login however if I refresh the page in the browser the session will probably be lost. For this reason the "autologin" does not work. The session is still in the database until expiry date. As soon as I log in again a new session record is created in the database. How can I solve this?

I tried logging in all the places in the console to see where things were slipping.

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session")
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
const passport = require('passport')
require('./strategies/local')
const cors = require("cors");

const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

require('./database')

const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;
app.use(express.json())
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:5173",
        credentials: true,
      })
);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'nkjhnjdjjkdhdjwgdzgdwg',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/express-react' }),
    cookie: { maxAge: 20000 },
}))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.method)
    next()
})
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/api/auth', authRoute)

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Express Server running on ${PORT}`));
```

**auth.js**

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router();
const User = require('../database/schemas/User')
const {hashingPassword, comparePasswords} = require('../utils/helpers');
const passport = require('passport');

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res)=>{
    console.log('logged in')
    res.send(200)
    console.log(req.session)
})

router.post('/register', async(request, response)=>{
    const { email } = request.body;
    const userDB = await User.findOne({ email })
    if (userDB){
        response.status(400).send({msg: 'User already exists'})
    }else{
        const password = hashingPassword(request.body.password)
        const newUser = User.create({ password, email})
        response.send(201)
    }
})

router.get('/autologin', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session && req.session.user){
        const user = req.session.user;
        res.status(200).json({loggedIn: true, user})
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

**local.js**

```
const passport = require('passport')
const { Strategy } = require('passport-local')
const User = require('../database/schemas/User')
const {comparePasswords} = require('../utils/helpers')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) =>{
    console.log('Seriealizing user...')
    console.log(user)
    done(null, user.id)
})
passport.deserializeUser(async (id,done)=>{
    console.log('Deserializing user...')
    console.log(id)
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(id)
        if(!user) throw new Error('User not found')
        done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        done(err, null)
    }
})

passport.use(
    new Strategy(
        {
            usernameField: 'email',
        },
        async (email, password, done) => {
            console.log(email)
            console.log(password)
        
            try{
                if (!email || !password) {
                    throw new Error('Bad request. Missing credentials.')
                }
                const userDB = await User.findOne({ email })
            if (!userDB) throw new Error('User not found.')
            const isValid = comparePasswords(password, userDB.password)
            if (isValid) {
                console.log('Authenticated successfully!')
                done(null, userDB)
            } else {
                console.log('Invalid authentication')
                done(null, null)
            }
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
                done(err,null)
            }
        }
    )
)
```

**Login.tsx**

```
import { FormEvent, useRef } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import SubmitButton from "./SubmitButton";
import SwitchButton from "./SwitchButton";
import { useUserContext } from "./Content";

type Context = {
    loggedIn: boolean,
    setLoggedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const Login = () => {

    const mail_ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
    const password_ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
    const {loggedIn, setLoggedIn} = useUserContext();

    const submit = async (ev: FormEvent) => {
        ev.preventDefault();

        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/auth/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "email": (mail_ref.current as HTMLInputElement).value,
                "password": (password_ref.current as HTMLInputElement).value
            })
        });

        const data = res.text();
        if(res.status == 200){
            setLoggedIn(true)
        }
        console.log(data);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
                <Input key={"asd"} ref={mail_ref} name="Email" type="text"></Input>
                <Input key={"dsa"} ref={password_ref} name="Password" type="password"></Input>
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center">
                <SubmitButton></SubmitButton>
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center">
                <SwitchButton></SwitchButton>
                </div>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

**Content.tsx**

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import Panel from "./Panel"
import Home from "./Home"
import axios from "axios";

type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

type Context = {
    loggedIn: boolean,
    setLoggedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const UserContext = createContext<Context | null>(null);

const Content = (props: Props) => {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAutoLogin = async () => {
            axios({
                method: "GET",
                withCredentials: true,
                url: "http://localhost:3001/api/auth/autologin",
              }).then((res) => {
                const data = res.data;
                if(data.loggedIn){
                    setLoggedIn(true)
                    setUser(data.user)
                }
                console.log(res.data);
                
              });
            }
        checkAutoLogin();
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            {props.children}
            <UserContext.Provider value={
                { loggedIn, setLoggedIn }
            }>
                {props.children}
                {loggedIn ? <Home /> : <Panel />}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}

export const useUserContext = () => useContext(UserContext) as Context;
export default Content;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).